# Pattern matching css rules

Tags: php, css, regex, pattern-matching

I have the following pattern:

```
[\{\}].*[\{\}]
```

With the following test strings (can provide more if needed):

```
}.prop{hello:ars;} //shouldn't match
}#prop{} //should match
}.prop #prop {} //should match
```

The purpose of the pattern is to find empty css rulesets. Can someone suggest how I go about excluding matches with characters between the second set of brackets? I will be updating the pattern as I get closer to a solution.

edit:
on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
this pattern: `[\}].*[\{]{1}[/}]{1}`
seems to have the desired result although it is breaking when transfered to php for reasons I don't understand.

edit: 
first apologies if this should be a separate question.
Using the pattern in the first edit in php:

```
    $pattern = "/[\}].*[\{]{1}[/}]{1}/";
    preg_match_all ($pattern, $new_css, $p);
    print_r($p);
```

When $new_css is a string of the content of an uploaded css file containing empty rulesets, $p is never populated. Yet I know this pattern is ok. Can anyone see what the issue is?

edit: **final solution**

```
//take out other unwanted characters
        $pattern = "/\}([\.#\w]\w+\s*)+{}/";
        //do it twice to beat any deformation
        $new_css = preg_replace ($pattern, '}', $new_css);
        $new_css = preg_replace ($pattern, '}', $new_css);
```

Comment: Why does  `\{\s*\}` not work?

Comment: I want to get the class / id ect as well as the brackets

Comment: Last year I did something similar in php with .css files, removed all comments, tokenized the text and detected all color definitions. So I am also curious if somebody will help you to find some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the pattern: `'/}([\.#]\w+\s*)+{}/'`

```
$new_css = "{}.prop{hello:ars;}
{}#prop{} //should match
}.prop #prop {} //should match
}.prop { aslkdfj}
}.prop { }
";

$pattern = '/}([\.#]\w+\s*)+{}/';
preg_match_all ($pattern, $new_css, $p);
print_r($p);
```

This outputs:

```
Array
  (
    [0] => Array
    (
      [0] => }#prop{}
      [1] => }.prop #prop {}
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
      [0] => #prop
      [1] => #prop
    )
  )
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. The pattern is slightly too restrictive and only captures the first class/id name. It fails on more complex selectors. I will see if I can adjust it.

Comment: correction to the above, it does not capture native elements such as body, ul, li ect.

Answer (score 1):

Try using single quotes around the regex, or doubling the `\` characters. The way PHP handles `\` in double-quoted strings is that `\{` becomes `{`, breaking the regex.